# How do I access image data in Xcode iOS app developer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I am VERY new to Xcode and even iOS apps/platform in general. I have a lot of image processing experience using other development platform environments and am looking to apply this toward iOS apps. I have noticed that nothing is mentioned for Xcode in regards to accessing image data and/or directly modifying it. Many people that have made tutorials seem to use an *image picker* but never have I seen where they say or show how to access the image data.

An answer to this would great. Guidance would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` provides the ability to display images from several different formats, but it's immutable -- you can't change the data it uses and expect to see the image change. Instead, you'll get an image in one of the underlying types and work with that. You'll probably want to read up on both Core Graphics (Quartz) and Core Image. For example, you can use `UIImage`'s `-CGImage` method to get the image as a CGImage and then use the Core Graphics `CGImage...()` functions to find out about the image data (format, bit depth, etc) and get the actual bits.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. The Core Image tool is in the right area of what I'm looking for. Trying to find out if Core Image provides capability for writing and implementing custom image processing functions. I would ultimately like to code and use a substantial quantity of state-of-the-art image processing techniques.

Comment: You can't write custom filters on iOS (although they are on OS X, so maybe someday...). Look instead at Brad Larson's [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), which provides similar functionality and IIRC custom filters.

Answer (score 0):

AVAssetLibrary can help you to modify image data.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[assetsLibrary assetForURL:photoUrl resultBlock:resultBlock
                      failureBlock:nil];
```

Using above code you will get asset of image in result block.

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *photoAsset)
{        
     ALAssetRepresentation *image_representation = [photoAsset defaultRepresentation];
     //Do the stuff to get-modify image data from image_representation...
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is this something done in Xcode? I am indeed looking to **modify** the image data. Thanks.

Comment: You mean modifying EXIF data?